# If statements forcing program to crash

Tags: java, android, eclipse, math, if-statement

I have asked a few questions before, however I have decided to go back to basics.

I am creating a maths android application, each page has three `TextField`s that the user can input a number into, I have parsed these `TextField`s into a double. However, say a user inputs a number into 2 of the `TextField`s, I would like the program to tell me the value of the third Text field.

At the moment I can get the program to run one calculation, however when I add the if statements in for the remaining two `TextField`s, the program crashes when I click calculate.
The Key behind the program is to discover which `TextField` is empty, so that the program can do the correct calculation.

I am currently trying `.getText().toString().isEmpty()`, but this is not working, I have also tried .length() == 0, however this is not working either.

When I run the emulator and click the calculator button, the program crashes when I add more variables in, however it is fine with just one calculation.

Can anyone help me figure out why the If statements are not working, and if possible can anyone offer a solution?

Sorry if my formatting is off, I'm relatively new to Java, below is the Java

```
Button calc1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.current_calculate);

    calc1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            EditText Charge1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number_input_2);
            EditText Time1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number_input_3);
            EditText current1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number_input_1);
            TextView Distances_answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Distances_answer);
            double charge = Double
                    .parseDouble(Charge1.getText().toString());
            double time = Double.parseDouble(Time1.getText().toString());
            double current = Double.parseDouble(current1.getText()
                    .toString());
            // Time is a class in Java
            if (current1.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                Distances_answer.setText("" + charge * time);

            } else if (Time1.length() == 0) {

                Distances_answer.setText(" " + charge / current);
            }

        }
    });
```

I have also supplied the XML in case it is needed

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background1"
android:gravity="fill"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
tools:context=".CurrentPage" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Current_hint"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:text="Welcome to the Current Calculation page.
     Hint - Use the check boxes to find the values that are missing "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Equation_letter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/current_calculate"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/current_calculate"
    android:text="     HELLO  "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Distances_answer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Equation_letter"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Equation_letter"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/current_calculate"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/t"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Q"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Q"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Q"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:gravity="right|top"
    android:text="t ="
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/custom3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/t"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/custom2"
    android:background="@drawable/check_box_new"
    android:button="@drawable/check_box_new" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/custom1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/number_input_3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/custom3"
    android:background="@drawable/check_box_new"
    android:button="@drawable/check_box_new" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Current_hint"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Current_hint"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Equation_letter"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/CurrentmainHelp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.31"
            android:text="HELP! This equation can be used to calculate the current of an object in amps. The correct equation to discover amps is I=Q/t. Where I = current, Q = charge flowing past a point in the circuit, and t = time taken for the charge to flow. Please note, Q is measure in coulombs and t is measured in seconds, with I being measured in amperes.

    Still need more help? "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Yes_Please"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.31"
            android:onClick="CurrentHelp"
            android:text="Yes Please"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/current_calculate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/Calculate_Current"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/number_input_2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/t"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/number_input_1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/number_input_1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/number_input_3"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/t"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/number_input_2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/number_input_2"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/custom2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/number_input_1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/number_input_1"
    android:background="@drawable/check_box_new"
    android:button="@drawable/check_box_new" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/number_input_1"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Q"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/current_calculate"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Q"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Equation_letter"
    android:layout_below="@+id/I"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:gravity="right|top"
    android:text="Q ="
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/I"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Q"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Q"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Current_hint"
    android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
    android:gravity="right|top"
    android:text="I ="
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
```

Comment: [Try to ask Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable) questions](http://www.sscce.org/) for quick help .

Comment: also, post stacktrace.

Comment: your app crash for a reason that is plainly stated in your error log. please read it.

Comment: right okay, the problem is i have often been criticised for being too compliant with sscce, so hence i am trying to give as much info as possible, and sorry njzk2, what's a stack-trace? when I say I am new to Java I mean noob new

Comment: Dude please you may be a wizard at java and know your way around eclipse but i really dont have a jar of glue?

Comment: @user3442326 Your question is fine except for not having the stack trace. When you say "is not working" ... we have to guess unless it's something completely obvious. In this case there's a couple different things that can be happening and knowing exactly what exception is being thrown is important.

Comment: okay, the answer below has sorted this out, but can you clarify for me exactly what and where i can find this stack trace? cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the application crashes because you are parsing the contents of your `EditText` to `double`s even though they may be empty. The `Double.parseDouble` function will throw a `NumberFormatException` if it cannot parse a `double` out of the given `String`. To fix this, perform a check for empty string before trying to parse, or catch the exception.

For example:

```
double charge = 0.0; // some default value
if (!Charge1.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
    charge = Double.parseDouble(Charge1.getText().toString());
}

double time = 0.0; // some default value
if (!Time1.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
    time = Double.parseDouble(Time1.getText().toString());
}

double current = 0.0; // some default value
if (!current1.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
    current = Double.parseDouble(current1.getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: you my sir are a genuine wizard, thank you very much that has worked a treat, thank you for not being so arrogant with you programming skills, cheers again, oh and i would try and give you some rep but apparently i cannot :? so maybe some one else can, cheers

Comment: No problem! In the future, you can debug such issues by looking at what caused the program crash. Check the log in your IDE for giant blocks of red text (those are usually Exception stack traces). They can tell you what line the problem is on. Here's an article on debugging Android applications: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/index.html

Comment: Oh cheers for that, Java is not my strongest suit, I just cannot get the hand of it, guess its not for everyone, cheers bud

Comment: Debugging is java is actually one of its strongest points. Here's information on how to view the stack trace console in Eclipse: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fconsole%2Fref-stacktrace_console.htm As you can see, there is some text that says "at..." and gives a line number. That is where the exception has occurred and was not handled. For info on exception handling, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/